# Re-direct URL to Add Trailing Slash in Sinatra

Tags: heroku, sinatra, rack, octopress

Have my app up on Heroku. Using [rack-canonical-host](https://github.com/tylerhunt/rack-canonical-host) to handle re-directs from myapp.heroku.com to the canonical domain. My domain registrar handles re-directs from the root domain.

I'm using Octopress (a Jekyll-based framework; Sinatra runs underneath) and **I want to re-direct all URL's *without* a trailing slash to the trailing-slash variant.** I would do this on the web-server side, but I don't have the ability to do so with Heroku.

I also assume that a 301 re-direct is the best practice for performing this re-direct.

I did have a look through the Sinatra docs but it seems that by default it's optional with the "?" on your routes, however my routes don't have this syntax but still handle with and without cases.

This is my current `config.ru`:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'rack/contrib'
require 'rack-canonical-host'

# The project root directory
$root = ::File.dirname(__FILE__)

class SinatraStaticServer < Sinatra::Base

  get(/.+/) do
    expires 3600, :public, :must_revalidate
    send_sinatra_file(request.path) {404}
  end

  not_found do
    expires 0, :public, :no_cache
    send_sinatra_file('404.html') {"Sorry, I cannot find #{request.path}"}
  end

  def send_sinatra_file(path, &missing_file_block)
    file_path = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'public',  path)
    file_path = File.join(file_path, 'index.html') unless file_path =~ /\.[a-z]+$/i  
    File.exist?(file_path) ? send_file(file_path) : missing_file_block.call
  end

end

if ENV['CANONICAL_HOST']
  use Rack::CanonicalHost, ENV['CANONICAL_HOST'], ignore: ['media.eatsleeprepeat.net', 'static.eatsleeprepeat.net']
end

use Rack::Deflater

run SinatraStaticServer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me for adding trailing slashes to any route that doesn't have one using a redirect:

```rb
get %r{(/.*[^\/])$} do
    redirect "#{params[:captures].first}/"
end

get %r{/.*/$} do
    "successful redirect for '#{request.path}'"
end
```

Comment: Perfect. Just the first block was needed. Tested locally and `/2012/blog-post-title` redirects cleanly to `/2012/blog-post-title/`

Answer (score 2):

Don't have a full answer for you, but I use redirects along the lines you suggest e.g.

```
get '/blog/2012/05/01/delegation/?' do
  redirect '/blog/2012/05/01/effective-delegation/', 301
end
```

I think for categories, octopress assumes category/index.html, hence the:

```
file_path = File.join(file_path, 'index.html') unless file_path =~ /\.[a-z]+$/i
```

line, which will convert domain.com/category to domain.com/category/index.html. Which I believe the the reason why some of your URL with or without the trailing slash continue to work.

Hope this helps a little...